# Assigning an interface to a component variable from a service variable

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

At the moment I have a service variable with a defined interface.

```
interface Bike {
    color: string;
    stock: number;
    wheels: number;
}
```

In my class I have defined the type of my variable:

```
export class BikeService {
    bikes: Array<Bike>;
    bike: Bike;
    ...
```

Now when I want to grab a bike from my service:

```
// Give it a return type of Bike so we have access to the interface
public getSpecificBike(i: number): Bike {
    this.bike = this.bikes[i];
    return this.bike;
}
```

When I use this function in my Component:

```
export class DisplaySpecificBikeComponent {
    _bikeService: BikeService;

    bike: any; // This is where the problem starts

    constructor(_bikeService: BikeService) {
        this._bikeService = _bikeService;
        this.bike = this._bikeService.getSpecificBike(1);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

At this point the only time I have access to the bike interface is directly from the service function, which makes sense since we've explicitly said that the return type of the getSpecificBike() function is of type Bike.

I'm curious if there is a way that does not require me to redefine the interface within the Component so that my Component variable has access to the interface and not just the function from the service.

If there is no way to accomplish this: Why doesn't the variable "bike" in the component inherit the interface of the function value?

Instead of setting

```
bike: any;
```

is there a way to set to

```
bike: Bike;
```

without redefining the interface in two places (Service and Component)?

Thanks!

Comment: How about exporting it from the service (i.e. `export interface Bike`) then import it in the component? Regarding Type Reference, I don't think the current state of TypeScript is that smart.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a clean quick way to do it for the time being.